# OpenCV c++ example into iOS project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I have a question about OpenCV and iOS.

I have try an C++ example with OpenCV.

Now I would to import this example into my iOS project. In this project I imported OpenCV iOS framework.

Now I have some import problems.

I don't know the corresponding import file of these:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing the framework like below? Once you do you should be able to call those files.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

For the header files you're looking for, they are:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make Your viewController.m file to **viewController.mm**(just rename it, nothing else), as it is objective C++ not objective-C, apply same thing to each and every .m file in which you are accessing opencv library
2. Add the code as explained by JamesGilesIV in your .pch file